# Animating elements in d3.js

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

I have a nice little network of nodes.

One is the central node and fixed, the others are flying around it, connected with links and influenced by the force field.

When the user clicks on one of the other nodes, this one is the new central node, and therefore fixed.

The idea would be to shift this clicked node to the center of the svg where the last central node was, so that the network doesn't move aside with every node you click.

Right now I can reset the position of this one node, but not move it to the desired position slowly.

Does anyone have an advice for me?

Edit 11/29/2013:

I've tried .transition() in the click-handler of the node (`group.select(this).transition().attr("cx", function(d) { return width/2; });`)
and right after appending the node.

Edit 2: The line of code given above was tested after entering the nodes.

I also tried to get the node via fixedNode, but this one doesn't have a transition-method. Afaik it does only contain the circle object, that does, by it's nature, not have a .transition()-method.

Edit 3: I've played around with the code for some hours, and now I found a way to do generell transitions. I added a  block of extra code after applying the force to the nodes (...call(force.drag);).

If I manipulate the radius, it works fine. Only problem is that all of the nodes are affected.

If I replace the r-attributes changes by `test.transition().duration(3000).attr("cx", width/2);`, it works but looks very strange, as the links sstill have the normal positions without the transition, and as soon as the transition is finished, the nodes hopp back!

So, if you could help me get the node I need as a single one and get the transition for positions to work, I would be happy!

Edit 12/02/2013:

Updated the sourcecode. Thanks to Lars Kotthoff, I can now move the circle. But the links still go to the old position of the node, and when the transition is over the circle goes back to the position they started at.

Added working code for you to copy. Please note that you need a json-file in the background ('rawData.json' located in the same folder).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dhtmlxSlider/codebase/dhtmlxslider.css">
    <script src="dhtmlxSlider/codebase/dhtmlxcommon.js"></script>
    <script src="dhtmlxSlider/codebase/dhtmlxslider.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.dhx_globalImgPath = "dhtmlxSlider/codebase/imgs/";
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .node text {
            pointer-events: none;
            font: 10px sans-serif;
            color: #FF7777;
        }
        .text {
            color: #FF7777;
        }
    </style>
    <title>ConceptMaps</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart" class="chart"></div>
    <div align="center" id="slider" onmouseup="paintIt();"></div>
    <div align="center" id="test"></div>
    <script>

        var reqNodes = [],
            reqLinks = [],
            fixedNode,
            testContainer = null,
            width = window.innerWidth*0.9, 
            height = window.innerHeight*0.9,
            mittelpunkt = "Perry Rhodan", 
            checklist = [],
            mitte = [],
            colorArray = ["#D3D3D2",  "darkblue", "#008000", "#F1AD45",  "#F2D667",     "#8BD3EB",     "#B74965",   "#67A175"],
            force = d3.layout.force().gravity(-0.1).distance(250).charge(-500).linkDistance(80).linkStrength(4).friction(0.6).size([width, height]);

            var group = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .attr("id", 'networkBox');

        var sld = new dhtmlxSlider("slider", 100, "arrow", false, 1, 5, 2);
            sld.setImagePath("dhtmlxSlider/codebase/imgs/");
            sld.setSteppingMode(true);
            sld.linkTo("test"); 
            sld.init();

        function getIndexInXML(attribute, targetContent) {
            if (xmlDoc == null) {alert("FAIL!");}
            var searchArray = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName(attribute);
            for (var i = 0; i < searchArray.length; i++) {
                if (searchArray[i].textContent == targetContent) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }//end getIndexInXML

        function getNodesFinalIndex(nameOfTarget) {
            for (var i = 0; i < reqNodes.length; i++) {
                if(reqNodes[i] != null){
                    if (reqNodes[i].name == nameOfTarget) {
                        return i;
                    }
                }
            }//for
        }//getNodesFinalIndex

        function getNodesIndex(nameOfTarget) {
            for(var i = 0; i < testContainer.nodes.length; i++){
                if(testContainer.nodes[i].name == nameOfTarget){
                    return i;
                }
            }//for
        }//getNodesIndex
        var linkBin = [];
        function getLinksIndex(nodeIndex){
            linkBin = [];
            for(var n = 0; n < reqLinks.length; n++){
                if(reqLinks[n].source.name == reqNodes[nodeIndex].name || reqLinks[n].target.name == reqNodes[nodeIndex].name){ //can not read name of undefined
                    linkBin.push(n);
                }
            }
            return linkBin;
        }//end getLinksIndex

        //getting the data from JSON-File
        d3.json("rawData.json", function(error, graph) {
            testContainer = graph;
            paintIt();              
        });//end d3.json

        function paintIt() {
            reqLinks = null;
            reqLinks = [];
            getNetParts(mittelpunkt, sld.getValue());
            update();
        }//end paintIt

        //------------ sort by used and unused nodes -------------------
        function getNetParts(searchedFor, depth) {      
            var temp = null;
            temp = [];

            //create a checklist with one element for each node in testContainer
            for(var pr = 0; pr < testContainer.nodes.length; pr++){
                checklist[pr] = false;
            }   

            var middle = getNodesIndex(searchedFor);
            temp.push(testContainer.nodes[middle]);     //asign middle node to temp
            checklist[middle] = true;   //note that middle has already been added to temp to prevent double assignments

            sortReqNodes(middle,1);

            checklist = null;
            checklist = [];
            var isThere = false;
            var freeSpaces = null;
            freeSpaces =  [];
            for(var pr = 0; pr < temp.length; pr++){    //new checklist, delete prev notes
                checklist[pr] = false;
            }
            for(var c = 0; c < reqNodes.length; c++){   //circle over the elements in 'reqNodes'
                    for(var cg = 0; cg < temp.length; cg++){    //look up if the element should be held there for the next version, too
                        if(temp[cg] != null && reqNodes[c] != null){
                            if(temp[cg].name == reqNodes[c].name){
                                temp[cg] = null;    //note the index of the node that doesn't need to be transfered
                                isThere = true;     //and make a mark
                                break;              //and break
                            }
                            else {reqNodes[c] = null;}
                            if(!isThere){
                                freeSpaces.push(c);
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }

            for(var x = 0; x < temp.length; x++){   //circle through temp
                if(temp[x] != null){        //if the element hasn't been deleted yet
                    if(freeSpaces.length != 0)  //if there is a free space, use it  
                            reqNodes[freeSpaces.pop()] = temp[x];   //transfer to reqNodes
                    else
                            reqNodes.push(temp[x]);                             
                }
            }


            //clean reqNodes up - deleting every 'null'
            for(var sl = reqNodes.length-1; sl >= 0; sl--){     //reverse loop - start with last element and end with first -> deleting elements won't disturb the loop
                if(reqNodes[sl] == null){   //if it is empty
                    reqNodes.splice(sl, 1);  //...remove it!
                }
            }


            for(var z = 1; z < reqNodes.length; z++){   //circle through stored Nodes
                if(reqNodes[z] != null){
                    for(var c = 0; c < reqNodes[z].connections.length; c++){    //inspect all of their connections 
                        for(var w = 0; w < reqNodes.length; w++){   //check all stored reqNodes for the one linked
                            if(reqNodes[w] != null){
                            if(testContainer.nodes[reqNodes[z].connections[c]].name == reqNodes[w].name){   //the node is available at reqNodes?
                                var source = null;                                  
                                var newLink = {
                                    "source":z,
                                    "target":w,
                                    "value":1,
                                };                          
                                reqLinks.push(newLink);                 
                            }
                            }
                        }   
                    }
                }   
        }

        function sortReqNodes(mitte, count){
                for(var y = 0; y < testContainer.nodes[mitte].connections.length; y++){ //stores every node connected with the main node in reqNode 
                        if(!checklist[testContainer.nodes[mitte].connections[y]]){  //if this one hasn't already been added
                            temp.push(testContainer.nodes[testContainer.nodes[mitte].connections[y]]);  //push a node connected with mitte to reqNodes
                            checklist[testContainer.nodes[mitte].connections[y]] = true;    //check - node has been pushed!
                        }
                        if(count < depth){  //if we haven't reached the desired depth yet
                            sortReqNodes(testContainer.nodes[mitte].connections[y],count+1);    //one more round, get the nodes connected with this one involved, too!
                        }           
                }
        }//end function sortReqNodes
    }//end function getNetParts

        function update() {

            group.selectAll(".link").remove();
            group.selectAll(".node").remove();

            //unfix any fixed nodes
            for(var count = 0; count < reqNodes.length; count++){
                if(reqNodes[count] != null){
                    reqNodes[count].fixed = false;
                }
            }

            var fixedNode = reqNodes[getNodesFinalIndex(mittelpunkt)];
            fixedNode.x = 900;  //Only works the first time...
            fixedNode.y = 300;

            fixedNode.fixed = true; 

            // fixedNode.px = width/2;      /*working, but makes the node jump -> ugly!*/
            // fixedNode.py = height/2;             

            link = group.selectAll(".link")
                .data(reqLinks);

            link.enter().append("line")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .style("stroke", "#000")
                .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value)*1.2; });

            node = group.selectAll("circle")
                .data(reqNodes);

            node.enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("r", 7)
                .style("stroke", "black")
                .style("fill", function(d) { return colorArray[d.group]; })
                .call(force.drag);

            node.append("name").text(function(d) { return d.name; });

            node.append("title")
                .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
            node.attr("name", function(d) { return d.name; });

            for(var oo = 0; oo < node[0].length; oo++){ 
                if(node[0][oo] != null){
                    if(node[0][oo].getAttribute('name') == mittelpunkt){
                        node[0][oo].style.stroke = "red";   
                        node[0][oo].style.strokeWidth = 3;
                    }
                }
            }

            node.filter(function(d) { return d.fixed == true; }).transition().duration(5000)
                    .attr("cy", height/2)
                    .attr("cx", width/2);
            node.filter(function(d) { return d.fixed == true; })
                    .attr("y", height/2)
                    .attr("x", width/2);

            node.on("click", function(d) {
                mittelpunkt = d.name;
                paintIt();
            });

            node.append("text").attr("dx", 12).attr("dy", ".35em").attr("fill", "#aa0101").text(function(d) {
                return d.name
            });

            //shows the fit article from the website www.perrypedia.proc.org, if you don't know the character on the node!
            group.selectAll(".node").on("dblclick", function(d) {
                window.open("http://www.perrypedia.proc.org/wiki/" + d.name);
            });

            force
                .nodes(reqNodes)
                .links(reqLinks)
                .start();


            group.selectAll('.not-fixed').call(force.drag);

            var groupDrag = d3.behavior.drag().on("drag", function(d) {
                // mouse pos offset by starting node pos
                var x = window.event.clientX - 430, y = window.event.clientY - 280;
                group.attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
                });
                CurrentGTransformX = x;
                CurrentGTransformY = y;
            })

            group.call(groupDrag);

            node.append("title").text(function(d) {
                return d.skill;
            });

            //HOVER for the nodes - makes it easier too determine which links belong to the node
            node.on("mouseover", function(d) {
                var selection = d3.select(this);
                var links2Change = getLinksIndex(getNodesFinalIndex(selection[0][0].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].textContent));
                var initialWidth = Number( selection.style("stroke-width") );
                var linksContainer = group.selectAll(".link");
                if(links2Change != null && links2Change != []){ 
                    for(var c = 0; c < links2Change.length; c++){
                        linksContainer[0][links2Change[c]].style.opacity = 0.2;
                    }
                }
            } )
            node.on("mouseout", function(d) {
                var selection = d3.select(this);
                var links2Change = getLinksIndex(getNodesFinalIndex(selection[0][0].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].textContent));
                var initialWidth = Number( selection.style("stroke-width") );
                var linksContainer = group.selectAll(".link");
                if(links2Change != null && links2Change != []){ 
                    for(var c = 0; c < links2Change.length; c++){
                        linksContainer[0][links2Change[c]].style.opacity = 1;
                    }
                }
            })

            link.append("title").text(function(d) {
                return d.group;
            });

            function getOffset(el) {
                var _x = 0;
                var _y = 0;
                while (el && !isNaN(el.offsetLeft) && !isNaN(el.offsetTop)) {
                    _x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
                    _y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
                    el = el.offsetParent;
                }
                return {
                    top : _y,
                    left : _x
                };
            }

            force.on("tick", function() {
                node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(15, Math.min(width - 15, d.x)); })      //restricts the x-coordinates to the inside of the SVG
                    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(15, Math.min(height - 15, d.y)); });    //restricts the y-coordinates to the inside of the SVG

                link.attr("x1", function(d) {
                    return d.source.x;
                }).attr("y1", function(d) {
                    return d.source.y;
                }).attr("x2", function(d) {
                    return d.target.x;
                }).attr("y2", function(d) {
                    return d.target.y;
                });
            });
        }//end function update()
    </script>
</body>
```

Edit 12/03/2013:

Added a manipulation of the x/y of my nodes.

Unfortunately this doesn't prevent the node from setting apart from the network for his transition. Doing the same manipulation on px/py instead doesn't help fixing the nodes jump from the target position of transition() back to the one assigned to force()...

rawData.json:

```
{
"nodes":[
    {"name":"Perry Rhodan","group":1,"skill":"Sofortumschalter, Erbe des Universums","connections":[1,2,3,4,5,7,13,17,19,18,22]},
    {"name":"Reginald Bull","group":1,"skill":"Techniker, Draufgaenger","connections":[12,0]},
    {"name":"Thora da Zoltral","group":2,"skill":"Hochmuetig","connections":[0,3,13,4]},
    {"name":"Crest da Zoltral","group":2,"skill":"Derengar","connections":[0,2,4]},
    {"name":"Atlan da Gonozal","group":2,"skill":"Der Einsame der Zeit","connections":[0,2,3,24]},
    {"name":"Homer Gershwin Adams","group":1,"skill":"fotografisches Gedaechtnis","connections":[0,7]},
    {"name":"Tatjana Michalowna","group":1,"skill":"Telepathin","connections":[7]},
    {"name":"Mutantenkorps","group":3,"skill":"1972 gegruendet von Perry Rhodan","connections":[0,8,9,10,11,12,15,16]},
    {"name":"Son Okura","group":1,"skill":"Telekinet","connections":[7]},
    {"name":"Wuriu Sengu","group":1,"skill":"Spaeher","connections":[7,14]},
    {"name":"Tako Kakuta","group":1,"skill":"Teleporter","connections":[7]},
    {"name":"Ras Tschubai","group":1,"skill":"Teleporter","connections":[7,12]},
    {"name":"Gucky","group":4,"skill":"Telepath, Telekinet, Teleporter","connections":[7,11,1]},
    {"name":"Thomas Cardif","group":1,"skill":"Rhodan-Imitator, Rhodans Sohn","connections":[0,2]},
    {"name":"Ismael ben Rabbat","group":1,"skill":"Raumschiffskommandant","connections":[9]},
    {"name":"Tama Yokida","group":1,"skill":"Telekinet, Materiewandler","connections":[7]},
    {"name":"Ernst Ellert","group":1,"skill":"Teletemporarier","connections":[7]},
    {"name":"Lotho Keraete","group":0,"skill":"Bote von ES","connections":[0,18,22,26]},
    {"name":"Homunk","group":0,"skill":"Bote von ES","connections":[0,17,26]},
    {"name":"Alaska Saedelaere","group":1,"skill":"Maskentraeger","connections":[0,20,21,22]},
    {"name":"Samburi Yura","group":0,"skill":"Kosmokratenbeauftragte","connections":[19,25]},
    {"name":"Sholoubwa","group":0,"skill":"Konstrukteur","connections":[19]},
    {"name":"Ennerhahl","group":0,"skill":"Beauftragter von ES, 'Mittel, Wege und Moeglichkeiten'","connections":[0,19,17,26]},
    {"name":"Delorian Rhodan","group":0,"skill":"Sohn von Perry & Mondra, Ex-Chronist von ES, Schöpfer einer Enklave","connections":[0,22,20,26]},
    {"name":"Theta da Ariga","group":2,"skill":"Geliebte Atlans","connections":[4]},
    {"name":"LICHT VON AHN","group":5,"skill":"Superintelligenz/Kollektivwesen","connections":[20]},
    {"name":"ES","group":5,"skill":"Superintelligenz","connections":[17,18,22,23]}
],
"links":[
    {"source":1,"target":0,"value":2},
    {"source":3,"target":0,"value":2},
    {"source":2,"target":0,"value":3},
    {"source":3,"target":2,"value":3},
    {"source":4,"target":0,"value":2},
    {"source":5,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":4,"target":2,"value":1},
    {"source":4,"target":3,"value":1},
    {"source":6,"target":7,"value":4},
    {"source":7,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":5,"target":7,"value":4},
    {"source":8,"target":7,"value":4},
    {"source":9,"target":7,"value":4},
    {"source":10,"target":7,"value":4},
    {"source":11,"target":7,"value":4},
    {"source":12,"target":7,"value":4},
    {"source":12,"target":1,"value":2},
    {"source":13,"target":0,"value":5},
    {"source":13,"target":2,"value":5},
    {"source":14,"target":9,"value":2},
    {"source":11,"target":12,"value":2},
    {"source":15,"target":7,"value":4},
    {"source":16,"target":7,"value":4},
    {"source":18,"target":22,"value":1},
    {"source":20,"target":22,"value":1},
    {"source":21,"target":19,"value":1},
    {"source":22,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":22,"target":19,"value":1},
    {"source":22,"target":17,"value":1},
    {"source":23,"target":22,"value":1},
    {"source":23,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":23,"target":20,"value":1}
]
}
```

Edit 12/04/2013:

As by now I got the transition working but the network is not pushed with the central node, I found out that the network itself gets its data about the node from fixedNode / the reqNodes-data of this node. If I change the fixedNode.px it snaps together.

So if I could add a line to the tick() that would update the px in every tick, I think this could work out as planned...

If you have an idea or see that I'm heading into a very wrong direction just leave a comment below or, if you want, create an answer!

Comment: Use `.transition()` before setting the new position.

Comment: Please could you provide a jsfiddle/tributary.io example to make it easier to understand what you would like to achieve

Comment: what you tried so for to animate????

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff: if I try to access my nodes via reqNodes, where they were stored, the given object doesn't have a .transition()-method... where can I get the node-object that has the transition-method?

Comment: Where exactly did you try to run that code?

Comment: right after defining the var fixedNode. I tried to replace the `fixedNode.px = width/2` and the y-declaration by a transition-operation.

Comment: No, use the transition when setting the new coordinates, i.e. `node.filter(function(d) { return d.fixed == true; }).transition().attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; }).//etc`.

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff: thanks for that line! Now the circle starts moving, but the network stays the same and the circle jumps back into position after reaching the destination...

Comment: That sounds like you haven't set the `fixed` property on that node or are resetting it. The node you move to the center needs to stay `fixed`.

Comment: Could you provide a complete working example please?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I think the force-layout doesn't get my new coordinates, that's why the links don't stay with the node. Where can I get the nodes position into the force-layout?

Comment: The positions of the nodes are determined by each node's `x` and `y` attributes. If you set those, the force layout will pick it up.

Comment: I really can't help you any further without a complete example (including data).

Comment: I can't really get it to work -- there's a lot of dependencies in there that you didn't include. Could you put everything up on e.g. [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I tried to, but can't get the dhtmlxSlider package into the project. You can download the package at http://www.dhtmlx.com/x/download/regular/dhtmlxSlider.zip  At the moment the plunker won't save and I can't share it... :/

Comment: Might be easier if you just package up the whole thing and send it to me by email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, here is the correct way to implement moving a node to its new position after its position has been fixed:

```
node.filter(function(d) { return d.fixed; }).transition().duration(1000)
    .tween("x", function() {
                var i = d3.interpolate(fixedNode.x, 900);
                return function(t) {
                  fixedNode.x = i(t);
                  fixedNode.px = i(t);
                };
     }).tween("y", function() {
                var i = d3.interpolate(fixedNode.y, 300);
                return function(t) {
                  fixedNode.y = i(t);
                  fixedNode.py = i(t);
                };
     });
```

This uses a custom tween function on the element that has been fixed, setting the `x`/`y` and `px`/`py` attributes at each step for the force layout to pick up.

Comment: that fixed it, thanks!! I have only one question left right now: what does `i(t)` do?

Comment: `i` is the interpolator and `t` is the current interpolation step (a number between 0 and 1). If you call `i(0)` you get the start value and with `i(1)` the end value. This makes it more convenient to compute the interpolation because all you have to do is pass numbers between 0 and 1.